# Win10 CMD to export only file names from directories and subdirectories

Tags: cmd, directory, windows-10

I want to use Win10 CMD to extract to a txt file, only the file names from a directory and the subdirectories.

The closest I've come is

```
V:\Scanned Pictures>dir *.jpg /s/d/a:-d "folderpath" > test1.txt
```

which DOES list only the file names, but also includes a "header" of the directory as in :

```
================================================================= Not wanted
 Volume in drive V is Pictures
 Volume Serial Number is C1FA-29F2

 Directory of V:\Scanned Pictures\1988-06 California trip
================================================================= Not Wanted
1988-06 California trip Kathleen Beach 1.jpg   <<<-- Just the file name
```

Comment: Any specific reason not to use PowerShell and make things way easier?

Comment: Thanks !!!                                                                                                                   
<sigh> I've never opened / used PowerShell  Old time (69 years old) CMD user only :-)

Comment: Can you please clarify by [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61859161/edit), exactly how you want the output to look. Currently it appears that you want everything except for the lines with the multiple `=` characters, and the answer you've accepted doesn't do that.

Comment: Thanks!I tagged the line which shows "just the file name"  the dir command returns the correct info in a line by line and all I want is the file name.

Answer (score 2):

Just add the /b option

```
dir *.jpg /b/s/d/a:-d "folderpath" > test1.txt
```

As per *dir /?* information, /b makes dir display bare format without heading or summary

Comment: Thanks, however the /b, when used in conjunction with subdirectories includes the full path with the file name Copied your string and here are a couple of lines:                                                                                         
V:\Scanned Pictures\1988-06 California trip\1988-06 California trip Kathleen Beach 1.jpg
V:\Scanned Pictures\1988-06 California trip\1988-06 California trip Kathleen Beach.jpg
V:\Scanned Pictures\1988-06 California trip\1988-06 California trip Kathleen Patricia.jpg

Answer (score 0):

There are many options for doing what you require, here are just some of them:

If you want exactly the same format as in your question, but with the none filename lines removed, then just use [findstr](/questions/tagged/findstr) to remove the unwanted lines.

You could do that by omiting lines which begin with a space, *(assumes that you do not have filenames beginning with a space character)*:

```batch-file
Dir /S/D/A:-D "folderpath\*.jpg" 2>NUL|%__AppDir__%findstr.exe /VBC:" ">"test1.txt"
```

If you want to further remove the empty lines, pipe it through another [findstr](/questions/tagged/findstr):

```batch-file
Dir /S/D/A:-D "folderpath\*.jpg" 2>NUL|%__AppDir__%findstr.exe /VBC:" "|%__AppDir__%findstr.exe /V "^$">"test1.txt"
```

---

If you don't need the wide column sorted format, but still want just the filenames then you could use [forfiles](/questions/tagged/forfiles):

```batch-file
%__AppDir__%forfiles.exe /P "folderpath" /M "*.jpg" /S /C "%__AppDir__%cmd.exe /D/Q/C If @IsDir==FALSE Echo @File">"test1.txt"
```

If you don't want them doublequoted then you could further expand it to do that:

```batch-file
%__AppDir__%forfiles.exe /P "folderpath" /M "*.jpg" /S /C "%__AppDir__%cmd.exe /D/Q/C If @IsDir==FALSE For /F \"Delims=\" %G In (@File)Do Echo %~G">"test1.txt"
```

Although, as [forfiles](/questions/tagged/forfiles) is a relatively inefficient command, and you're now using a [for-loop](/questions/tagged/for-loop) anyhow, you could just use a [for-loop](/questions/tagged/for-loop) directly:

```batch-file
(For /F "Delims=" %G In ('Dir /B/S/A-D "folderpath\*.jpg" 2^>NUL')Do @Echo %~nxG)>"test1.txt"
```

If you wanted to ensure that only files with the file extension `.jpg` were output, *(as opposed to those beginning with `.jpg`, as with the [dir](/questions/tagged/dir) command)*, then you could also use the [where](/questions/tagged/where) command instead.

```batch-file
(For /F "Delims=" %G In ('%__AppDir__%where.exe /R "folderpath" *.jpg 2^>NUL')Do @Echo %~nxG)>"test1.txt"
```

---

**[Edit /]**

The following examples have been included as a result of your posted answer, which shows that `folderpath` was not necessary, as you're working in the current directory. I've not recopied the text, just the code examples in the same order:

```batch-file
Dir /S/D/A:-D *.jpg 2>NUL|%__AppDir__%findstr.exe /VBC:" ">"test1.txt"
```

```batch-file
Dir /S/D/A:-D *.jpg 2>NUL|%__AppDir__%findstr.exe /VBC:" "|%__AppDir__%findstr.exe /V "^$">"test1.txt"
```

```batch-file
%__AppDir__%forfiles.exe /M *.jpg /S /C "%__AppDir__%cmd.exe /D/Q/C If @IsDir==FALSE Echo @File">"test1.txt"
```

```batch-file
%__AppDir__%forfiles.exe /M *.jpg /S /C "%__AppDir__%cmd.exe /D/Q/C If @IsDir==FALSE For /F \"Delims=\" %G In (@File)Do Echo %~G">"test1.txt"
```

```batch-file
(For /F "Delims=" %G In ('Dir /B/S/A-D *.jpg 2^>NUL')Do @Echo %~nxG)>"test1.txt"
```

```batch-file
(For /F "Delims=" %G In ('%__AppDir__%where.exe /R . *.jpg 2^>NUL')Do @Echo %~nxG)>"test1.txt"
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I ran the first one which resulted in a 0 byte text1.txt  I tried several others with the same result. A syntax error?  I tried to deduce, but I am not smart enough to untangle it.   Thanks again!

Comment: @tom, I have no control over what you're using in place of `folderpath`, or depending upon whether you're replacing that with a full or relative location, what your current ditectory is at run time. I can assure you however, that if you've changed only that string and nothing else, _(not even its surrounding doublequotes)_, and at the time you run the command line, the folderpath` location is available, _(according to the above)_, and contains somewhere within its tree at least one file with a `.jpg` extension, they will work. There's no syntax error in any of my posted codes above.

Comment: From the examples you've posted @tom, you've a volume labelled `Pictures`, which has been assigned the drive letter `V:` Within the root of that drive, there's a directory named `Scanned Pictures`, which is your current directory in your provided command line. Your provided command then uses `folderpath` which can only be a made up name because the provided output clealry shows no directory named `folderpath`. In order to get the output you've provided, you must have replaced `folderpath` with either `1988-06 California trip` or `V:\Scanned Pictures`. So to make it work replicate those things.

Comment: Compo - Thanks for your help and explanations. Very helpful in working out a solution.

Comment: @tom, your last comment has not validated that my code actually does work. Also, if you're satisfied that any of the answers provided so far, are acceptable solutions, you should mark your preferred one as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I found a 2 part solution.

dir *.jpg /s/b/a-d > test.txt
    - Produces a file that only has the path listed along with the file name
Copy contents to Excel 
Excel Find / Replace *\ with null
    - Removes the path

- Extra step not listed in my original question
  Data Text to Columns to separate date taken from the file name

Thanks to everyone for your suggestions and input, you put me on a path to find a solution.

Thanks and stay safe!

Comment: Whilst this may explain that you've solved your issue, it is not an answer to the posted question. I have made an edit to my answer to include the changes necessary to remove the `folderpath` string, which was clearly not needed.